# Choose random color pallet from the list on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need some help with Javascript.

Description: there are 3 different color combinations (pallets). Every combination has 3 colors.

Goal: randomly choose color combination on page load and change elements like: background-color, font-color, underline-color.

Problem: can't figure out how to make it for color combination, but not a 1 color like in code example below.

Example:

- Pallet-1: red, blue, green
- Pallet-2: yellow, cyan, orange
- Pallet-3: cyan, orange, blue

  1. Script randomly choosing Pallet-2.
  2. Change background-color to yellow, font-color to cyan, border-color to orange.

Sorry if it's too simple, but I spent a day and found a solution for random color pick **of 1 color only** from the list, but **can't make it work with color combinations**.

Thanks in advance.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','cyan','orange'];
  var new_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
  $('#color-div').css('background-color',new_color);
});
```

CSS:

```
#color-div{
  border:1px solid gray;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="color-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40r2gcsk/7/)

Comment: You are telling us what you want to achieve, and you are showing us your code, but you're not telliing us what exactly is not working (any errors etc.?). There is no actual question in your question...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited the question. The problem is: I can't figure out how to make random color combination (pallet). My example choose and change only one color.

Comment: Yes, but it changes 1 color and I'm looking for solution to randomly pick a combination of colors and apply it to different elements in html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer after clarification (picking a random colour set):**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var palettes = [
    ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    ['yellow', 'cyan', 'orange'],
    ['cyan', 'orange', 'blue']
  ];
  var randomPalette = palettes[Math.floor(Math.random() * palettes.length)];
  
  var new_bgcolor = randomPalette[0];
  var new_textcolor = randomPalette[1];
  var new_bordercolor = randomPalette[2];

  $('#color-div').css({
    'background-color': new_bgcolor,
    'color': new_textcolor,
    'border-color': new_bordercolor
  });
});
```

```css
#color-div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="color-div">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Old answer before the clarification (picking three random but unique colours):**

You have to remove the randomly selected colour from the array of colours before picking the next one. You can do so by using `Array.prototype.splice()`.

As there is no css property for text underline colour, I changed the border colour in this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'orange'];
  var new_bgcolor = colors.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), 1);
  var new_textcolor = colors.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), 1);
  var new_bordercolor = colors.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length), 1);

  $('#color-div').css({
    'background-color': new_bgcolor,
    'color': new_textcolor,
    'border-color': new_bordercolor
  });
});
```

```css
#color-div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="color-div">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment. But it doesn't randomly change color combination (like in example Pallet-2), it just randomly choose color for every element from the list.

Comment: Ok now I get what you are really trying to do. I'll rewrite the code to reflect hat. But could you please specify why, when palette 2 is yellow, cyan and orange, the colours should change to white, black, and red?

Comment: When the active colors are yellow, cyan and orange (active Pallet-2) the colors should change to red, blue, green (Pallet-1) or cyan, orange, blue (Pallet-3) on next load. Sorry it was a mistake in description. Thanks

Comment: But your last comment now contradicts the changes you made to the question... I updated my answer according to the current state of the question. Please check if it's what you need.

Comment: I'm so sorry for confuse. Let me explain more clear. There are 3 combination of colors, on page load script should randomly choose a combination (not a color) and apply it to 3 elements. On the next page load it makes same procedure, randomly choosing combination of colors and applying it to 3 elements. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

Gonna leave this just in case somebody wants the code without jQuery

```
window.onload = () => {

  const palettes = [
    ["red", "blue", "green"],
    ["yellow", "cyan", "orange"],
    ["cyan", "orange", "blue"]
  ];
  const randomPalette =
    palettes[Math.floor(Math.random() * palettes.length)];

  let bgColor = randomPalette[0];
  let textColor = randomPalette[1];
  let borderColor = randomPalette[2];

  const div = document.getElementById("color-div").style;

  div.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  div.borderColor = borderColor;
  div.color = textColor;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
var colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow','cyan','orange'];
var getRandomColor = () => colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
var color1 = getRandomColor(); 
var color2 = getRandomColor());
var color3 = getRandomColor();
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#color-div-1').css('background-color', color1);
  $('#color-div-2').css('background-color', color2);
  // etc...
}
```

and your HTML would contain these new classes of course:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="color-div-1" />
  <div id="color-div-2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but if I understand it right it doesn't randomly change color combination (like in example Pallet-2), it just randomly choose color for every element from the list.